# Jquerymobile div at absolute center

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, positioning

I am using jquerymobile and I have div with class allertMessage inside div data-role="content". I want this div to be in absolute center of page (vertical+horizontal). I cant use this:

```
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
```

because it will not center my element. Also tried margin:auto but it didnt worked. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you don't know the width and height to start with then you'll need to use jQuery/javascript to get the width and height of your element then center it after you grab them.

Comment: I can use text-align: center; to center it horizontaly but still need to handle vertical align.

Comment: Use @kakarott's method below to center your DIV both vertically and horizontally using jQuery/JS once you grab the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

HTML

```
<div id="alertdiv">
    <h1>This is an alert</h1>
    <p> And here is the alert content</p>
    <p>And some more content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#alertdiv{
    position:absolute;   
    background:orange;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toppos=($(window).height()/2) - ($("#alertdiv").height()/2);
    var leftpos=($(window).width()/2) - ($("#alertdiv").width()/2);
    $("#alertdiv").css("top", toppos).css("left",leftpos);
});
```

Comment: it worked but you set fixed widht and height. But what if I use it on smaller screen? or at larger screen? Right now mi text is divided into 5 lines. It should be ok on small screens, but when someone load this app on tablet then my text should be in one line so the div width needs to change dynamicaly.

Comment: I have only set the dimension per css, because I have no content to put in. It works with variable dimension.

Comment: so can you please change your code so it would only align the div verticaly (you can use fixed height I think)? I tried remowing widht from css and var leftpos ... from js. I also removed .css("left",lefpos) but it isnt aligning the div verticaly.

Comment: ok, it's edited. I have taken out the fixed dimensions and added some content to the div.

Comment: $("#alertdiv").css("top", toppos).css("left",leftpos); is the same than $("#alertdiv").css({"top": toppos,"left":leftpos}); but writting more

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if your division height and width are 400px (both) . Then you can do this :

```
#div{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -200px;/* half of #div height*/
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -200px;/* half of #div width*/
}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, you can absolute center by jQuery too.

use this small script to center :

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) +
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) +
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Now you can center any element just by adding :

```
 $(element).center();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/72LPR/)

***Note: It will center the element on every load, Not on screen change (And I dont think your screen size will be changed.)***

Comment: well I dont know my div height and widht because I cant know in forward on what screen resolution will my app be used (mobiles have different screnn resolution);

Comment: If your div have a fixed width and height, this technique will not be effect by resolution.

Comment: my div can have fixed height but it cannont have fixed widht. Or if you want it can have fixed width but it must be 100% of screen.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript and position dinamically the div as with jquery for example:

```
var WindowHeight = $(window).height();
```

EDIT

```
$('#myDiv').css({top: ((WindowHeight - myDivHeight) / 2 ) + "px"});
```

somthing like that I use it and works ok, didnt check my code maybe theres a typo or a missing '' or something. I think is the best way to have it done.

Do the same with  $(window).width();

Comment: will not work, because it doesn't integrate the size of the box itself. The box will not be centered, it will be positioned with the origin at the center.

Comment: I just edited becuase you are right, just take the element and sbstract it for the middle